# Returning true in setOnLongClickListner

Tags: java, android

Can any one please tell me why it is necessary to return true in the end of setOnLongClickListner(); when I try to change the return type from Boolean to void then it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Can any one please tell me why it is necessary to return true in the end of setOnLongClickListner();
```

It is not necessary to return true, it is necessary to return a boolean, so it can be false.

From the docs:

> Returns boolean   true if the callback consumed the long click, false
>   otherwise.

This means, if you return true the event stops propagating. Otherwise, the event keeps propagating and other related events will be called.

For example, if you return false, your OnLongClick event gets fired. After finishing, your onClickListener will be triggered. If you return true, event will stop in OnLongClickListener.

```
when I try to change the return type from Boolean to void then it gives me an error
```

You are implementing an interface. The method is already defined, but not implemented. You cant change it. For more info about this:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the fiction. So you have to follow the function prototype exactly. That's the language rules you cannot argue with.
Therefore, You **cannot** change return type.

It's necessary to return true to tell Android OS that function got executed properly without error

Comment: but what if we return false?

Comment: Returning false will basically just prevent the default action from happening. Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

we return **TRUE** in `setOnLongClickListner()` telling the framework that the touch event is consumed and no further event handling is required. and if we return **FALSE** it will never trigger the actiion.